# How do you use Java GeoTools to add text and display them on JMapFrame's map content?

Tags: java, geotools

I know how to create a layer and display points on JMapFrame. But I do not know how to add a text string next to a point? Below is the code to display multiple coordinates on JMapFrame, I thought adding text strings would have similar codes. Please help, thanks!

```
    SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder builder = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
    builder.setName("feature1");
    builder.setCRS(DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84);
    builder.add("location", Point.class);
    final SimpleFeatureType TYPE = DataUtilities.createType("Points", "points", "the_geom:MultiPoint");
    SimpleFeatureBuilder featureBuilder = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(TYPE);
    GeometryFactory geometryFactory = (GeometryFactory) JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory();
    MultiPoint points = geometryFactory.createMultiPoint(coordinates); //be careful of the order
    featureBuilder.add(points);
    SimpleFeature feature = featureBuilder.buildFeature(null);
    DefaultFeatureCollection featureCollection = new DefaultFeatureCollection("internal", TYPE);
    featureCollection.add(feature);
    Style style = SLD.createPointStyle("square", Color.red, Color.red, 1.0f, 8.0f);
    //Style style = SLD.createSimpleStyle(TYPE,Color.RED);
    Layer layer = new FeatureLayer(featureCollection, style);
```

That is how I created my layer and below I managed to display my points on a shape file. I did not post all my codes because it was too many, but this is the general implementation.

```
    MapContent map = new MapContent();
    map.layers().add(layer);
    JMapFrame.showMap(map);
```

Can anyone help me with adding text strings next to my points? Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a `TextSymbolizer` to your style to draw the text.

```
Style style = SLD.createPointStyle("square", Color.red, Color.red, 1.0f, 8.0f);
StyleBuilder styleBuilder = new StyleBuilder();
String attributeName = "name";
Font font = styleBuilder.createFont("Times New Roman", 10.0);
TextSymbolizer textSymb = styleBuilder.createTextSymbolizer(Color.black, font, attributeName);
Rule rule = styleBuilder.createRule(textSymb);
style.featureTypeStyles().get(0).rules().add(rule);
```

should do it. The key line is `TextSymbolizer textSymb = styleBuilder.createTextSymbolizer(Color.black, font, attributeName);` that creates the symbolizer using `Black` as the text color, `font` as the font to use (this must be a font on your machine) and finally `attributeName` is the data column (attribute) that should be used to create the label. If you instead want a fixed string then you can use [`styleBuilder.createStaticTextSymbolizer`](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/geotools/styling/StyleBuilder.html#createStaticTextSymbolizer-java.awt.Color-org.geotools.styling.Font-java.lang.String-) which just uses the last parameter as the labeltext.

In general for real code it is better to use the `StyleBuilder` rather than the `SLD` methods for full control of your style. Internally GeoTools styles are represented as OGC Styled Layer Descriptors (SLD) so the [SLD Cookbook](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/cookbook/) may be helpful. I also regularly use this method when debugging.

```
private static void printStyle(Style style) throws TransformerException {

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    SLDTransformer transformer = new SLDTransformer();
    transformer.setIndentation(2);
    transformer.transform(style, bos);
    String styleStr = bos.toString();
    System.out.println(styleStr);
  }
```

Which will print this for the above code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><sld:UserStyle xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
  <sld:Name>Default Styler</sld:Name>
  <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
    <sld:Name>name</sld:Name>
    <sld:Rule>
      <sld:PointSymbolizer>
        <sld:Graphic>
          <sld:Mark>
            <sld:Fill>
              <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#FF0000</sld:CssParameter>
            </sld:Fill>
            <sld:Stroke>
              <sld:CssParameter name="stroke">#FF0000</sld:CssParameter>
            </sld:Stroke>
          </sld:Mark>
          <sld:Size>8.0</sld:Size>
        </sld:Graphic>
      </sld:PointSymbolizer>
    </sld:Rule>
    <sld:Rule>
      <sld:TextSymbolizer>
        <sld:Label>
          <ogc:PropertyName>name</ogc:PropertyName>
        </sld:Label>
        <sld:Font>
          <sld:CssParameter name="font-family">Times New Roman</sld:CssParameter>
          <sld:CssParameter name="font-size">10.0</sld:CssParameter>
          <sld:CssParameter name="font-style">normal</sld:CssParameter>
          <sld:CssParameter name="font-weight">normal</sld:CssParameter>
        </sld:Font>
        <sld:LabelPlacement>
          <sld:PointPlacement>
            <sld:AnchorPoint>
              <sld:AnchorPointX>0.0</sld:AnchorPointX>
              <sld:AnchorPointY>0.5</sld:AnchorPointY>
            </sld:AnchorPoint>
          </sld:PointPlacement>
        </sld:LabelPlacement>
        <sld:Fill>
          <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#000000</sld:CssParameter>
        </sld:Fill>
      </sld:TextSymbolizer>
    </sld:Rule>
  </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
</sld:UserStyle>
```